# C# practice print star'*'

Tags: c#

I am practicing to generate the star in the following result.

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

with code:

```
private static void ShowStar(int p)
    {
        StringBuilder foward = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
        {
            foward.Append('*');
            Console.WriteLine(foward.ToString());

            reverse.Insert(0,foward.ToString().Substring(1) + "\r\n");
            if (i == p) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reverse.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

But I want to more simple way to print it, does anyone have any good ideas?

thanks a lot!!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to first collect the lines into an array, then print out the array. It's much more cleaner this way. Imagine, if latter, you'd like to modify your code and want to write it into a file as well, or do other processing with it.

```
    private static void ShowStar(int p)
    {
        // collecting data. In more complex environments this should be
        // in a separate method, like var lines = collectLines(p)
        var lines = new string[p*2+1];
        var stars = "*";
        for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
        {
            lines[i] = lines[p * 2 - i] = stars;
            stars += "*";
        }

        // writing the data. In more complex environments this should be
        // in a separate method, like WriteLines(lines)
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void ShowStar(int p)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < p * 2; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', (i < p) ? i : p * 2 - i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the star pattern printing into two loops.

First loop prints

```
*
**
```

That is from row number 1 to row number `(n / 2)`.

Whereas second loop prints

```
*** 
**
*
```

That is from row number `(n / 2 + 1) to n`. Where `n` is the maximum row number.
Hope it will make your code easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
string CreateArrow(int count)
{
    // Only one buffer
    StringBuilder sbAll = new StringBuilder();

    // The arrow needs an arrowhead
    if(count % 2 == 0) count++;

    // Create the arrowhead
    string s = new string('*', count);
    sbAll.AppendLine(s);

    // the rest of the arrow
    for(int x = count-1; x>0; x--)
    {
        s = new string('*', x);

        // before the arrowhead
        sbAll.Insert(0, s + Environment.NewLine);

        // after the arrowhead
        sbAll.AppendLine(s);

    }
    return sbAll.ToString();
}
```